# How to put elements to left menu sonataadmin

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm trying to resolve 2 problems in Symfony 2 sonata Admin that I accualy have.
First , I cannot put my service element through left menu , I have it in main dahsboard view and i don't know how to put it and I cannot find it in repository
[Screenshot](https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/6Z8lcDVEJh0/H4~7~Pl7GdfvlLvL)

My Catalog class

```
<?php
namespace AdminBundle\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class CatalogAdmin extends  Admin
{
    protected $baseRouteName = 'admin_category';
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'category';

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $categoryFieldOptions = array('multiple'=>true);
        $formMapper
            ->add('name')
            ->add('parent_id','sonata_type_model',$categoryFieldOptions)
            ->add('alias')
            ;
    }


    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('parent_id')
            ->add('alias')


            ->add('_action','actions',array(
               'actions'=>array(
                   'show'=>array(),
                   'edit'=>array(),
               )
            ));
    }
    }
```

And service:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.categoryedit:
        class: AdminBundle\Admin\CatalogAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Category", label: "Kategoria" , show_in_dashboard: "true" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - AdminBundle\Entity\Category
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [AdminBundle]]
```

And Config File (only imports tag:):

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: @AdminBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml}
```

And My second problem is , when I'm trying to click anything I got error:

```
No entity manager defined for class AdminBundle\Entity\Category
```

How to resolve that problems ?
Best Regards

21.01.2014
I created errror in config.yml to see error message

```
at Processor->processConfiguration(object(Configuration), array(array('title' => 'NewProject', 'title_logo' => '/bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png', 'dashboard' => array('blocks' => array(array('position' => 'left', 'type' => 'sonata.admin.block.admin_list')), 'groupsa' => array('admin.category' => array('label' => 'Kategorie', 'items' => array('sonata.admin.categoryedit'), 'roles' => array('ROLE_ADMIN'))))))) in SonataAdminExtension.php line 78
```

I can see that label my item sonata.admin.categoryedit doesn't have any position or something , Is that OK ? maybe i should change something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Guys , problem solved.
I didnt give permission to admin via database to my user , so that was very bad mistake ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can define it in config. I reccomend to look at full config

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html

Config related to link in left menu is:

```
 sonata_admin:
      dashboard:
           groups:
               name.of.your.first.level.of.menu:
                   label: name_of_item_here
                   items:
                        - sonata.admin.categoryedit
                        - another_service_name1
                        - another_service_name2
```

Items will appear as menu links grupped by name_of_item_here

Regards entity manager, i'm not sure but try to add this line to your config

```
 sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
   # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
      entity_manager: ~
```

level of sonata_doctrine_orm_admin is the same as sonata_admin (i mean level inside yml)

Comment: Thanks for answer.
1. Menu is still clear , i added what you wrote and nothing helped, maybe i need some permissions to left menu ?
2. I have that line in my config about orm_admin

Comment: You can check out admin-bundle/Resources/standard_layout.html.twig. (in vendor)There is block name  side_bar_nav in 198 line and this block is protected by      {% if app.security.token and is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN') %}

Comment: I have got this role and I'm really confused, but it's not worikng. Very strange

Answer (score 0):

Regarding {% if app.security.token and is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN') %} :

Did you try to output this condition and check if it really validates to true?

I mean adding something like for example COMPARISON_RESULT:{{ app.security.token and is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN') }}  just before this comparison?

Or just try to put some text inside it? Just to check if it enters inside?